# Solve for scaling matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve for an unknown diagonal matrix $\alpha$ that scales the columns of matrix $A$ to satisfy the equation.

$$
(A \; \alpha)^T \; M \; (A \;\alpha) = I
$$

An exact solution is not required an approximate solution would be fine.

Currently I scale the columns to unity and then find the factors column by column as follows:

$$
\alpha_i = \frac{1}{A_i^T \; M \; A_i}
$$

Where $A_i$ is the columns/vectors of $A$ where the columns have been scaled to 1 and $\alpha_i$ is the corresponding scale factor for the column.

Edit:
$M$ and $A$ are known matrices.

Comment: Just to clarify, $M$ and $A$ are just some known matrices with no special structure?

Comment: Yes $M$ and $A$ are known matrices, $\alpha$ is unknown.